# Query XML to filter down to

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to create a list that is the results of an inner join between two xml lists and then filter on an external list of keys that are in a DataTable. A code example is not necessary as long as I can be pointed to something explaining how to do it.

Whut I'm working with is the returned data from Microsoft Cognitive Services Text Analytics Topic Detection. There are two sections in the XML. The first is the list of items I need to get. The other has a list of keys I have references for.

An example of the returned XML is on their [Quick Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/quick-start) page. Do a find on page for: >>> **"status": "Succeeded"** <<< to get to it.

You'll see in the bottom part, the *"topicAssignments"* section, of the example XML the value **"documentId": "1",** That's the key I have in the DataTable. The Document also has one-to-many *"topicId"* associated to it. That's where the relationship is set between the *"topics"* section and the *"topicAssignments"* section

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As often as not, writing up the question clarified my ideas enough to Google it successfully.

https://www.google.com/search?q=linq+inner+join+on+xml&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS631US631&oq=linq+inner+join+on+xml

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wriju/2008/03/24/linq-to-xml-join-xml-data/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/joins-using-linqtoxml1

Comment: Actually, the above "solution" wasn't the right one. What I eventually realized was that the List object has a .Join method. Worked great.